# Finding the set of values for the parameter of a line such that the perpendicular distance from the line to a plane is less than 4

Tags: vectors

> The plane $Π_1$ has equation
>
> $$r=i+2j+k+ \theta (2j-k) + \phi (3i+2j-2k) $$
>
> Which is $$2x+3y+6z=14$$
>
> The line $l$ has equation
>
> $$r = 3i + 8j + 2k + t(4i + 6j + 5k)$$
>
> The point on $l$ where $t = λ$ is denoted by P. Find the set of values of λ for which the perpendicular distance of P from $Π_1$ is not greater than 4.

---

This is a diagram I drew to picture this :

[image]

> where $n=2i+3j+6k$

---

What I tried:

**I thought of finding the critical value at which distance is 4**

$$3i+8j+2k + \lambda (4i+6j+5k) + \frac {4}{u} (2i+3j+6k)=(i+2j+k)+ \theta (2j-k) + \phi (3i+2j-2k)$$

> Where $u = \sqrt{(2^{2}+3^{2}+6^{2})}=7$

Which is very long method, and still didn't get right.

---

My book did a simple way, which I don't understand, Please help me understand  how the book did it:

**Book Method**

Perpendicular distance, p, of P from l in terms of 1 parameter

$$p =\frac{1}{7}2(3+4λ)+3(8+6λ)+6(2+5λ)−14$$

$$= |4+8λ|$$

$$p\leq 4 \implies –1 \leq λ \leq 0$$

---

It seems to me that they have taken the plane equation and replaced 0 with p in:

$$2x+3y+6z-14=0$$

To:

$$2x+3y+6z-14=p$$

And then substituted the line onto this, but how can they do that. The line does not meet/on the plane to substitute into this formula. Please help. I don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we let $P=(x_1,y_1,z_1)$, the distance from P to the plane is given by

$d=\left|\text{comp}_{\vec{n}}\vec{v}\right|$ where $\vec{v}$ is a vector from P to any point Q in the plane and $\vec{n}$ is a normal vector for the plane.

This gives $d=\displaystyle\frac{\left|2x_1+3y_1+6z_1-14\right|}{\sqrt{4+9+36}}=\frac{\left|2(3+4\lambda)+3(8+6\lambda)+6(2+5\lambda)-14\right|}{7}$

$\hspace{.78 in}\displaystyle=\frac{\left|28+56\lambda\right|}{7}=\left|4+8\lambda\right|=4\left|1+2\lambda\right|$.

Comment: What does comp mean? :) it means component of the perpendicular vector along v?

Comment: Do you know a link that has how this happens in detail? Coz I really don't understand how you got $|2x_1+3y_1+6z_1-14|$ as the component. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: That is right; $\text{comp}_{\vec{n}}\vec{v}=\frac{\vec{v}\cdot\vec{n}}{|\vec{n}|}$, so if $Q=(x_0,y_0,z_0)$, this gives $\frac{|(x_0-x_1)n_1+(y_0-y_1)n_2+(z_0-z_1)n_3)|}{\sqrt{n_1^2+n_2^2+n_3^2}}$.  Here is a link: http://mathinsight.org/distance_point_plane

Comment: Thank you very much :D , okay according to the formula -14 does not come right? Because there is no -d?

Comment: I understood :) don't bother answering about d, I know why now :)